# Find all the rows in a table which doesnt have checkboxes by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an html structure like

```
<div id='myDIV'>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>No check box </td><td>Row2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row4</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My problem is to hide all the **tr** which doesnt have checkbox in that.

To find the rows which has check box is `jQuery('#myDIV tr input:checkbox')`

**It lists down Row 1, 3, 4**

**But I need Row 2**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you build your table? It might be easier to mark those rows that have checkboxes with a distinct class on render and then select by class.

Comment: The table content is dynamic, if it had been static, I wouldnt have posted this question.

Comment: I know it's dynamic, that's why i asked you how you generate it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('#myDIV tr:not(:has(input:checkbox))')
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e40tbx6p/

- [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: @SashiKant Note : *"Because* `:checkbox` *is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using* `:checkbox` *cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM* `querySelectorAll()` *method. For better performance in modern browsers, use* `[type="checkbox"]` *instead."*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
jQuery('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length === 0;
}).hide();
```